# Xcode 14.1 Debug error “does not contain expected binary artifact” error

Tags: ios, swift, ios16, open3d, xcode14

we are getting this error for a while since xcode has released new versions past few months but still didn't got any solution

we trying to use open3d-ios swift package

Here’s Swift package code for binary target of git zips

```
 .binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a", url: "https://github.com/kewlbear/Open3D-iOS/releases/download/0.0.20220804014308/libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a.xcframework.zip", checksum: "a652bd2ab0c76623bb27268acbd0832326031cb2acc71eda4bc0e36849f64e84"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a", url: "https://github.com/kewlbear/Open3D-iOS/releases/download/0.0.20220804014308/libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a.xcframework.zip", checksum: "55c0f90841fa15c7aa6e3de24e719936af7ea09bfe314eb3a1e44b97e0b49a76"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a", url: "https://github.com/kewlbear/Open3D-iOS/releases/download/0.0.20220804014308/libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a.xcframework.zip", checksum: "a5f2cd5c510dc92920aba4d23e7ee771c43e6f1187930707bccaeeac00e76a57"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a", url: "https://github.com/kewlbear/Open3D-iOS/releases/download/0.0.20220804014308/libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a.xcframework.zip", checksum: "9245503d7f4968faa706edce41da5cff5dd2330227234815d7b3855723e189e1"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D.a", url: "https://github.com/kewlbear/Open3D-iOS/releases/download/0.0.20220804014308/libOpen3D.a.xcframework.zip", checksum: "84915b1c787bc97f52b8cc39f51c9452a39ca6c5b83677cf422fd9e876e0794d"),
```

for above code snippet we are getting above error

```
Showing Recent Messages
downloaded archive of binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a'

downloaded archive of binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a'

downloaded archive of binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a'

downloaded archive of binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a'

downloaded archive of binary target 'pybind.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'pybind.a'

downloaded archive of binary target 'libOpen3D.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D.a'

fatalError
```

we even tried unzipping those assets and referencing those locally

```
.binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a", path: "Users/apple/Documents/Open3D-iOS-main/cartifacts/libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a.xcframework"),
.binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a", path: "artifacts/libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a.xcframework"),
.binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a", path: "artifacts/libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a.xcframework"),
.binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a", path: "artifacts/libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a.xcframework"),
.binaryTarget(name: "libOpen3D.a", path: "artifacts/libOpen3D.a.xcframework"),
```

still we are getting following error

```
Showing Recent Messages
local binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_liblzf.a'

local binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhull_r.a'

local binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_qhullcpp.a'

local binary target 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D_3rdparty_rply.a'

local binary target 'libOpen3D.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'libOpen3D.a'

local binary target 'pybind.a' does not contain expected binary artifact named 'pybind.a'

fatalError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue! Downgrading to XCode 13.4 solved my problem! The root cause is that Xcode 14 is not compatible with XCFramework name with ".a". I filed a bug report but got no response yet. For more details please see the Github link below.

[Similar issue discussion from Open3D-iOS](https://github.com/kewlbear/Open3D-iOS/issues/38)

Comment: **Thanks for your answer! I edited the extensions of files and similarly all the names in package.swift  and it worked** _but I am still getting following errors but there no issue in creating the build so for now I am ignoring  it_ ' /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SceneDepthPointCloud-bdoxxdhrtojssueehjvimkgmdhkv/SourcePackages/checkouts/NumPy-iOS/Sources/NumPySupport/site-packages Couldn't load project at: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SceneDepthPointCloud-bdoxxdhrtojssueehjvimkgmdhkv/SourcePackages/checkouts/NumPy-iOS/Sources/NumPySupport/site-packages'

Comment: In Xcode 14.1 I'm still getting build error No such module "Open3DSupport" :( Are you able to import Open3DSupport in Xcode 14?

Comment: Yes it worked at my side I use Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b). I do get same error sometimes but following steps like :( resetting package , clean build or again deleting and adding the package ) fixes that issue

Comment: Thanks! I tried many times with Xcode 14.1 but wasn’t able to get around :( I’ll try again with your build and exact steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After some time researching I found out that I wasn't referencing the packages right. In my case, I changed to
`path: "./MyLibrary.xcframework` instead of `path: "MyLibrary.xcframework`.

Before this I only could add packages and build in a lower version of Xcode.

Full example:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyLibrary", targets: ["MyLibrary"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(name: "MyLibrary", path: "./MyLibrary.xcframework")
    ])
```